# Apache Flink writeAsCsv() method to write a tuple of objects

Tags: java, stream, bigdata, apache-flink

I'm following Apache Flink tutorial to cleanse a stream of TaxiRide events. The resulting stream is printed to the console. And now I want to write it to the csv file.

```
        // configure event-time processing
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        // get the taxi ride data stream
        DataStream<TaxiRide> rides = env.addSource(
                new TaxiRideSource(path, maxEventDelay, servingSpeedFactor));

        DataStream<TaxiRide> filteredRides = rides
                // filter out rides that do not start or stop in NYC
                .filter(new RideCleansing.NYCFilter());

        filteredRides.print();
```

I've tried the following but getting the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The writeAsCsv() method can only be used on data streams of tuples.`

```
DataStreamSink<TaxiRide> rides = filteredRides.writeAsCsv("/resources").setParallelism(1);
```

When I'm making a `DataSet<Tuple1<TaxiRide>> rides1 = filteredRides.writeAsCsv("/resources").setParallelism(1);` It leads to a compiler error.

What should I do to write the resulting cleansed stream of TaxiRide objects to a csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataStream` and `DataSet` belong to separate APIs that cannot be mixed. Hence, the compile error.

The error message "The writeAsCsv() method can only be used on data streams of tuples." means, that you have to convert the `DataStream<TaxiRide>` object into a `DataStream` of tuples to write it as a CSV file.
This can be done with a simple `MapFunction`:

```
DataStream<Tuple9<Long, Boolean, DateTime, DateTime, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Short>> rideTuples = filteredRides
   .map(new TupleConverter());
```

with `TupleConverter` being defined as

```
class TupleConverter implements MapFunction<TaxiRide, Tuple9<Long, Boolean, DateTime, DateTime, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Short>> {

  public Tuple9<Long, Boolean, DateTime, DateTime, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Short> map(TaxiRide ride) {
     return Tuple9.of(ride.rideId, ride.isStart, ...);
  }
}
```

Once you have the `DataStream` `rideTuples`, you can write it to a CSV file.